# okhttp post request with authentication

Tags: java, post, okhttp, http-authentication

I am using the okhttp (4.4.0) java library to send a post request to a webservice i created.
Additionally that webservice requires basic authentication and does only accept post-requests.
The webservice is behind a proxy that simply forwards https requests to http requests on port 8080.
My code looks like this:

```
    ...
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("foo", this.foo)
                        .add("bar", this.bar)
                        .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://localhost/myWebApp")
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", "OkHttp Bot")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic("myUser", "myPwd"))
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
      }
      return response.body().bytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
```

The request fails with the following error:

`Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=501, message=Not Implemented, url=https://localhost/myWebApp/}`

The webservice's 'myWebApp' doGet method is configured to send a 501 Not implemented status message.
But as I do a post-request the doGet method should not get called.

By taking a look in the access log of my webserver I found the following:

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2020:09:05:24 +0200] "POST /myWebApp HTTP/1.1" 302 -
    127.0.0.1 - myUser [30/Mar/2020:09:05:25 +0200] "GET /myWebApp/ HTTP/1.1" 501 1029
```

So there is both a post request and a get request.
It looks like there is at first a try to send the post body (without authentication?) and then a get request with authentication which is denied by my webservice.

Is there a way to make this work for me? Am I missing something? Please help!

Comment: Could you share the proxy configuration? It may be something there.

Comment: It is the pretty standard apache ssl.conf. I just added these few lines 
`ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /MyWebApp http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp
ProxyPassReverse /myWebApp http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp`
in the virtualhost section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I solved my own problem. Thanks @Yuri for pointing me there.
I just added a "/" at the end of the url in my code and it worked like a charm.

```
...
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://localhost/myWebApp/")
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", "OkHttp Bot")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic("myUser", "myPwd"))
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
...
```

For some reason (I don't know yet but maybe someone else can enlighten me) any given url without a trailing slash is redirected to the same url with a trailing slash.
Standard browsers can deal with this circumstance, the okhttp client seems to struggle there.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should return a 401 challenge for the client to authenticate.  But is sending a 302 for some reason.  Is it setup to redirect for a user in a browser with a custom login page?

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Authenticate.java

Comment: I was wondering about that, too. I ran the linked sample code, it produced following output: `Authenticating for response: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://localhost/MyWebApp/}
Challenges: [Basic authParams={realm=Authentication required}]
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=501, message=Not Implemented, url=https://localhost/MyWebApp/}
 at Authenticate.run(Authenticate.java:39)
 at Authenticate.main(Authenticate.java:46)`

Comment: The access log looks like this: `127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020:07:18:51 +0200] "GET /MyWebApp HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020:07:18:51 +0200] "GET /MyWebApp/ HTTP/1.1" 401 994
127.0.0.1 - myUser [31/Mar/2020:07:18:51 +0200] "GET /MyWebApp/ HTTP/1.1" 501 1029`